# Detect pandas column(s) causing row uniqueness

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to drop duplicate rows in a pandas DataFrame with many columns. The problem is that there must be some column with unique values, because
`df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=True)`
does not drop all of the rows I would expect it to.

Selecting two rows that appear to me to be duplicates, I tried a visual comparison but was unable to identify a difference between them. Because there are many columns, visual inspection is time consuming and error-prone. **I would like an automated way to find the columns for which there are differences across a list of rows**. I am not sure how to do this in pandas, to which I am fairly new. I didn't find any previous questions on this topic.

Edit: I am interested in detecting the columns with unique values, as opposed to merely dropping duplicates based on a predetermined subset of columns.

Comment: Please see [ask] and how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two rows, iterate over the values of each row to find out where they differ:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'a': [1, 1], 'b': [1, 1], 'c': [1, 2], 'd': [1, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['foo', 'bar'])
```

> ```
>      a  b  c  d
> foo  1  1  1  1
> bar  1  1  2  3
> ```

```
differences = [i for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(df.loc['foo'].values, df.loc['bar',:].values)) if x!=y ]
df.iloc[:, differences]
```

> ```
>      c  d
> foo  1  1
> bar  2  3
> ```

Now, for a set of rows, you would need to make all possible pairwise comparisons between rows, each time potentially with a different result.